# jquery ajax redirecting upon error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have the following action on my controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveDeposit(DepositCreateScreenDTO depositCreateScreenDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            //Do some saving
        }
        catch (FaultException<FaultDTO> ex)
        {
            Danger(string.Format(ex.Message));
            return Json(new { Message = ex.Message });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Danger("Er was een probleem bij het maken van de afgifte");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This action gets called as follows :

```
$('#SaveButton').click(function () {
    var url = $('#SaveButton').data("url");
    var overview = $('#SaveButton').data("overview");
    var flag = true;
    if (flag) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                DepositTemplateVersionId: $('input#DepositTemplateVersionId').val(),
                depositDate: $('#depositDateValue').val()
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (result) { document.location = overview; },
            error: function (x, t, e) { }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

When I get an error I am redirected to the document.location which is set in the success.
And on that page, the errormessage is displayed.
Now I don't want to be redirected to that "success-page".
In case of an error I want to stay on my current page.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are returning null or a FaultException message on exception at server. That's still a success for ajax on client. You need to check in success callback if result is not having any exception message or null then redirect. Better add variable in json, something like Success:true/false, when exception set it to false. then check result.success is true then redirect.

Comment: @SSA : Im doing the following now : success: function (result) { if (result == "") { document.location = overview; } }
So I'm not redirecting when there is a message in result.
But my page doesn't refresh, so I'm not seeing the errormessage.
When I refresh manually (pressing F5) the errormessage is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to SSA I found the answer to my problem.

I'm doing the following now :

```
success: function (result) { if (result == "") { document.location = overview; } else { document.location.reload();} }
```

And now page refreshes, displaying the error when there was an error.